# Dispatching action when a custom observable is cancelled

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

The newest version of redux-observable doesn't give any access to `store` and we have to dispatch actions by returning them from epics. I don't know how to dispatch actions when some observables are cancelled, for example by `switchMap` effect. For instance:

```
const counter = new Observable(observer => {
  let i = 0;
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
      observer.next(i++);
  }, 1000);

  return {
    unsubscribe: () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
      // how to dispatch action here like { type: 'COUNTER_ABORTED' }?
    }
  };
});
```

Or maybe this is RXJS antipattern what I want to do? Maybe there is some `switchMap` trick I could use to do additional things for cancelled observables?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot emit a value through the teardown logic. Maybe you can call a function in the `complete` callback to get the actions? `counter.subscribe(event => /* ... */, null, () => getActions())`

Comment: Thats why I would need to call `store.dispatch`, but I don't have access to it there and it seems hacky to provide this value by a closure etc, so I search for rxjs solution if this exists. Re your suggestion, how can I know in `complete` whether observable was successful, errored or cancelled? Pity we dont have callback `onCancel` in observer instance.